# pip install numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip, install

Я хочу установить numpy, я пробовала:

1. pip install numpy
   Команда «pip» не найдена. Возможно, вы имели в виду:
   command 'ip' from deb iproute2 (5.15.0-1ubuntu2)
   command 'zip' from deb zip (3.0-12build2)
   command 'pic' from deb groff-base (1.22.4-8build1)
   command 'php' from deb php-cli (2:8.1+92ubuntu1)
   command 'php' from deb php8.1-cli (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.1)
   Try: sudo apt install
2. sudo apt install python3-pip

   Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
   Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
   Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
   Пакет python3-pip недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
   пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
   доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

   E: Для пакета «python3-pip» не найден кандидат на установку
3. python -m pip install --upgrade pip

   Команда «python» не найдена. Возможно, вы имели в виду:
   command 'python3' from deb python3
   command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
4. python -m pip install --upgrade pip

   /usr/bin/python3: No module named pip

У меня ничего не работает, нету pip. Поэтому pip install numpy не работает, что делать?

Comment: А в какой папке вы пытаетесь установить numpy?

Comment: А так: python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip, еще вариант скачать вручную https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py и запустить

Comment: А в какую папку нужно было?

Comment: @RobiyaObidjonova В папке с питоном должна быть папка Scripts - действия с pip делайте там.

Comment: спасибо, мне удалось установить - pip, numpy))))))))))))))